# How to check task status by task id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My code:

```py
import time

def func(sleep_time):
    task = Thread(target=task_func, args=(sleep_time,))
    task.start()
    return task.ident

def task_func(t):
    time.sleep(t) # some task example
    return "some task result"
```

I know, there is `is_alive()` method, but if I have many tasks like this:

```py
for i in range(3):
    func(i)
```

output (tasks IDs) gonna be like:

```
123
456
789
```

So how can I check task status by ID, something like this:

```py
def check_status(task_id):
    return is_alive(task_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `threading.enumerate()` to list all the active threads and then check if the desired one id active.

`threading.enumerate()` returns a list of all Thread objects still alive. 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html

```
import threading
def check_status(task_id):
    my_threads = threading.enumerate()
    for elem in my_threads:
        if elem.ident == task_id:
            print(elem)
```